# How to know if there is an already locked table MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

I'm trying to restore a MySQL dump from a list of SQL file such as :

```
for file in *.sql; do mysql ... < $file;done
```

This strategy works perfectly but for a certain table it doesn't. Actually it stays blocked for ages untill I kill the command.
Here is the status shown with 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST'

```
LOCK TABLES `ms_lims_properties` WRTIE
```

I can't explain why my load stay locked like this, where as the table should only contain 5 lines.

Here is an sample of the corresponding sql file :

```
LOCK TABLES `ms_lims_properties` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE ms_lims_properties DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO ms_lims_properties VALUES (1...
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ms_lims_properties` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;
```

It uses MyISAM as an engine and so I don't know how to check if there is any lock somewhere...
The state I can see from MySQL administrator is :

`Waiting for table`

I've tried drop the database, recreate it with the same result... :(

Has someone any clue?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using LOCK TABLES `ms_lims_properties` WRITE;

SO if you are locking your table before doing an insert then you cannot insert as the table is locked.

Comment: Hi CloudyDna, actually this set of commands is created by the dump for each sql files (1 file = 1 table) and is written in each file. However, other table are populated normally wihtout any lock such as the one for 'ms_lims_property' table. E.g.:

LOCK TABLES `identification` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `identification` DISABLE KEYS */;INSERT INTO `identification` VALUES (64115,1457842,44,

Comment: would be much easier to understand if i can look at the server myself and then probably fix it for you. Because from the question I cannot fully understand the problem

Comment: The problem is that the table 'ms_lims_properties' is not loded with data. It is well created but it looks like once the table is created the query 'Lock table ... Write' get stuck for ages and the insert is not done.
Something like the query to lock the table is locked. 
This is shown running 'SHOW FULL PORCESSLIST'